# Migration from Firebird 1.5 to PostgreSQL-9.3

Tags: database, postgresql, firebird, postgresql-9.3, firebird1.5

I'm migrating all the tables and data from Firebird 1.5 to PostgreSQL-9.3.

The software was build using Delphi 7 and I'm migrating to Java web.

My question is:

**How to make this works in PostgreSQL?**

```
 TELA BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 SEGMENT SIZE 80
```

Comment: When asking questions about migrating from one technology to another, it's a good idea to include a description of the desired functionality, as well as the current implementation. That way, a Postgres expert who knows nothing about Firebird can show you how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'll edit my question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of Firebird's `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0` in Postgres is `bytea`.

So the column definition would be `tela bytea`

Comment: `SEGMENT SIZE 80` is mostly a hold over from ancient times, it means that the blob is to be consumed in segments of 80 bytes (it is more a hint for client applications for writing to or reading from the blob). It doesn't mean that the maximum size is 80. So using this check constraint would have the wrong effect.